# sort of arrays and their position

Tags: c, arrays, algorithm, sorting

I have a sort problem.

I have two array

```
int a[] ={index1,index2,index3...indexI};
int b[] ={num1,num2,num3.......numI};
```

Array b[] is having numbers in random order but their position corresponds to position in a[].
For example num1 is the value of index1, num2 is the value of index2.

The problem is:

I need to sort the b[] elements in descending order, at the same time I need to move the a[] elements position according to the sorted order of b[].

I can sort b[] in descending order using one of the sort algorithm but I am not able handle the simultaneous move of the a[] elements according to the b[] position change. 
My final output  I am expecting is a[] indexes arranged in descending order of their values in b[].

Please help.

Thanks

Comment: Any particular language?

Comment: Could you create an array of structs and just sort that?

Comment: @Chowlett any language will do :) Even logic or pseudocode will do. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I get it correcty yu want to have something like this a = [0 1 2]; b = [5 2 8] and after sorting a = [1 0 2]; b = [2 5 8].

Which ever sorting algorithm you must just remember to change index arrays when changing number's position:

eg. swapping two positions (pseudocode)

```
swap(i, j): // i, j - indexes
   (b[i], b[j]) = (b[j], b[i]) // swap values
   (a[i], a[j]) = (a[j], a[i]) // swap the indexes
```

Answer (score 7):

```
int a[] ={index1,index2,index3...indexI};
int b[] ={num1,num2,num3.......numI};
int c[] = {{num1, index1}, {num2, index2}...{indexI, numI}}
sort(c);
for i = 0 to c.len
  print c[i][1]
```

In c++ I would use a vector of pairs. In other languages you can use a structure.

Comment: I want to do it in matlab. Matlab cant sort vector pairs! Any advise ?

Answer (score 1):

After you've sorted `b`, you can sort `a` by a comparison function that looks up values in `b`.

```
// assuming b is visible at the module level, you can pass this to qsort
int compare_by_indexing_into_b(void const *a, void const *b)
{
    int i = *(int const *)a;
    int j = *(int const *)b;

    return b[i] - b[j];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do it in two paths: first, sort `a` using your favorite sorting algorithm, but instead  of comparing `a[i]` to `a[j]` directly, compare `b[a[i]]` to `b[a[j]]`. Now re-arrange `b` according to the indexes in `a` - and you are done.

The second step may look like this (in pseudocode):

```
var c = new int[b.length]
for (int i = 0 ; i != a.length ; i++)
    c[i] = b[a[i]]
b = c
```

Answer (score 1):

This shows one of the downfalls of using *parallel arrays* instead of an array of struct. The simple solution would be to convert your code to use

```
 struct {int index, num;} a[] = {{index1, num1},{index2, num2}, ...};
```

If your codebase already makes heavy use of parallel arrays, you can write a sort which is aware of such difficulties. You could pass it an array of arrays, rather than a single one, and write the sort to perform its swaps across every array, while only performing comparisons on the first. In other words:

```
void sort_pa(void **arrays/*NULL-terminated*/, int len,int size, int(*cmp)(...)))
```

Which you would then use:

```
int a[] ={index1,index2,index3...indexI};
int b[] ={num1,num2,num3.......numI};
int *c[] = {b, a, NULL};

sort_pa(c, I, sizeof **c, cmp);
```

Answer (score 1):

Using qsort, you will sort the array a using the following comparison expression:

```
b[*(int*)elem1] - b[*(int*)elem2]
```

where elem1 and elem2 are the two pointer arguments to the comparator function (let b be visible by the function).

This will leave the array b untouched, and b[a[i]] will give the b elements in decreasing order.